# How do I automate opening and downloading a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, web, download, wget

There is a website that has an HTML `<video>` element in it when loaded, however this element isn't present if I just download it with `wget`, so I guess it gets loaded by a script that's only ran when the page is opened in a browser. I need the video's direct link, in an automated fashion.

Could you please tell me if I have the right idea, and if there is a possible solution? Could I for example run a browser from the command line, let it load the page and all of the referenced content, then save the `.html` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [headless Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome), potentially with [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/) scripting for that.

Though, depending on the details, there may be easier options that would get you what you need. It sounds like you're currently trying to scrape a third party website using `wget`. Instead of, or in addition to, requesting the .html content with `wget`, you could request the relevant javascript file and then extract the video url from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After all it turned out that my research effort wasn't needed, as the video url is included somewhere else, even in the version of the website that wget downloads.